# Lightswitch calender grid

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

If I have a table containing operatives and a table containing appointments by time, with a one to many relationship to the operatives table. I want to create a grid with the operatives represented at the top of each column, with a time line of appointments listed below is this at all possible or is there a control or similar that could do this easily?

Many thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

Html client can easily use a gant control.
The silverlight client does not have this natively.

Either make a custom control (xaml)
Or use a third party control

I have no third party to recommend, big dll's tend to complicate things.